# Apps become transparent when the desktop is directly behind them

Tags: gnome, nautilus, visual-artifacts

I'm new to Ubuntu and installed some well-known apps, but now my file explorer becomes transparent when I hover over it if the desktop is directly behind. The same happens with WPS office.

However, if I go full screen, the problem disappears. The problem also disappears if there is another window opened behind it.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: file manager with transparent patches]

I tried to grab a screenshot, but the problem disappears there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Issue with graphics card: post info on your graphics, provided by following command `sudo lshw -class display`. Include that in your question: use "edit"

Comment: Update: After disabling all Gnome extensions, the problem disappeared

Comment: You could enable them one by one to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: You've mentioned you have a bug, if you do you're off-topic here (this is a Q&A Support site and not a bug tracker). If you were after support this is the place, but you start off saying you have a Bug report (thus you don't belong - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).  Bug reports need to be made on launchpad; please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs.... ps: *You've already got a few off-topic close votes, if you were after support I'd suggest rewording your question to be about support & not bugs*